# How to clear a drive encryption

Tags: system

Actually, 2 questions:

I have a separate, solid state drive that was encrypted when I first started using it.  However, the encrypt key was changed and so I can't access the drive.  Presently, I can neither mount nor clear the drive.  Thus:

1. How to best identify the drive so that I don't go and wipe out my / directory?  I know the computer-drive are attempting to talk (I see the device busy light flashing) but I can't determine if the drive is mounted anywhere.
2. What is the best way to remove the encryption?  I was thinking of simply reformatting the drive.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You generally have two kinds of drive encryption:

1. Native drive encryption (e.g. drive it self receives clear text and encrypts it)
2. Operating system encryption.

## Drive encryption.

This is typically described as hardware encryption. The drive receives the key, and caches it. All crypto operations are performed by the drive. If this is the case for your drive, you may be able to use `hdparm` to issue a secure erase to the drive, or reset it in some fashion.

### Operating system level encryption.

This is the default used by the Ubuntu installer. The operating system is performing the encryption, and encrypted data is sent to the drive. The crypto operations are performed by the CPU in the computer, not by the disk.

As this is the common for Ubuntu, I'm assuming this is what you have. In this case, you can simply delete the offending partition, and create new partitions.

This can be done using gparted. Simply run `pkexec gparted /dev/sdX` where `/dev/sdX` is the device in question. Select the partition, select Delete, create a new one, and apply the action to the device. This will remove the old partition, and create a new one in its place.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I go about mounting the drive when it doesn't show up in /dev or /usr/dev?